# realloc in cgi script

Tags: c, cgi

Consider the following source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{
        char *input;

        char *sql;
        sql = (char *) malloc(strlen("SELECT url, title FROM crawl.crawled " + 1));
        sql = "SELECT url, title FROM crawl.crawled ";
        sql = (char *) realloc(sql, 1000);
}
```

In my ubuntu 20.04/nginx/cgi setup this is causing a `502 Bad Gateway`. The offending line seems to be the `realloc` as when I comment this out the problem goes away.

Why? What's the problem with `realloc` and cgi scripts?

Comment: `sql = ...; sql = ...; sql = ...;` Think about that for a moment. What you're doing is similar to `int a = 10; a = 20; a = 30;` and then wonder why `a` isn't equal to `10`.

Answer (score 0):

Everything in this code is wrong.

- `strlen("SELECT url, title FROM crawl.crawled " + 1)` does pointer arithmetic on a string literal, which is nonsense. Should have been `strlen(...) + 1`.
- sql = ... yet again discards the previous assignment to that variable (and creates a leak). You probably meant to use `strcpy`.
- The realloc call doesn't make any sense, it's just bloat. It will however crash & burn because of the bug on the previous line.

You can replace all of this with something along the lines of:

```
const char SELECT_URL[] = "SELECT url, title FROM crawl.crawled ";
char *sql = malloc (sizeof SELECT_URL);
memcpy(sql, SELECT_URL, sizeof SELECT_URL);
```

Where `sizeof` implicitly takes the null terminator in account.

Comment: Well, the first one isn't *nonsense*, but it's still not what s/he meant.